Creating Signed Symmetric Group in MAGMA
I want to create in MAGMA the subspace of the general linear group $\operatorname{GL}_n (\mathbb{F}_5)$ consisting of matrices with only entry $\in \{ 1, -1 \}$ in each row and column and all other entries are zero. That is, I want to create the signed symmetric group of matrices over $\mathbb{F}_5$.
If $n = 2$, then the signed symmetric group has $2^n \cdot n! = 8$ elements. This is kinda doable since the group has only $8$ elements and can be listed explicitly.
However, for large values of $n$, say $n=5$, this would be tiresome.
How do I create the signed symmetric group of matrices in MAGMA?
Thank you in advance for any help. Below is my sample code.
>F5 := FiniteField(5);
>
>GL25 := GeneralLinearGroup(2, F5);
>
>A1 := Matrix(F5,2,2,[1,0,0,1]);
>A2 := Matrix(F5,2,2,[4,0,0,4]);
>A3 := Matrix(F5,2,2,[1,0,0,4]);
>A4 := Matrix(F5,2,2,[4,0,0,1]);
>A5 := Matrix(F5,2,2,[0,1,1,0]);
>A6 := Matrix(F5,2,2,[0,4,4,0]);
>A7 := Matrix(F5,2,2,[0,1,4,0]);
>A8 := Matrix(F5,2,2,[0,4,1,0]);
>
>SignSymGrp := sub<GL25|A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8>;
>SignSymGrp;


G:=sub<GL(n,5)|Generators(ShephardTodd(2,1,n))>;

Disclaimer: this answer gives a different approach, though not in Magma (that I don't know) but in a "parent language", SAGE, just to convey the following plain idea:
The multiplicative group SSM of "signed permutation matrices" is obtained by left-multiplying all ordinary permutation matrices by all diagonal matrices with entries $\pm1$
(as far as I know, it means that SSM is a semidirect product).
See SAGE program below generating the good list :
$$\displaystyle \left[\left(\begin{array}{rr}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{rr}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{rr}
0 & -1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{rr}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\right]
$$
Remark: right-multiplying would have of course generated the same set.
 from itertools import product ; # cartesian product of sets
 n=2
 K=GF(5)
 v=[vector(K, b) for b in product(vector(K,[-1, 1]), repeat=n)]
 show(v)
 S=SymmetricGroup(n)
 L=[];
 for g in S:
    M=g.matrix()
    for d in v:    
       D=diagonal_matrix(d)
       P=D*M
       L.append(P)
 show(L)


I did some MAGMA tests, and it seems that the signed symmetric group of matrices over $\mathbb F_5$ can be generated by only  2 or 3 elements, depending if $n$ is even or odd.
Here a MAGMA script returning the signed symmetric group of matrices over $\mathbb F_5$ as a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n (\mathbb{F}_5)$:
F5 := FiniteField(5); n:=5; // Fix n as you need
GLn5 := GeneralLinearGroup(n, F5);

Z:=ZeroMatrix(F5,n,n);

G1:=Z;  G1[1,2]:=1; G1[2,1]:=-1;
for j in {3..n} do G1[j,j]:=1; end for;  // First generator 

G2:=Z; G2[n,1]:=1;
for j in {1..n-1} do G2[j,j+1]:=1; end for;  //Second generator

SignSymGrp:=sub<GLn5|G1,G2,-G1>; // For n odd, we need a third generator: -G1

// For sure SignSymGrp is contained signed symmetric group of matrices over F_5;
// let us check it has the right order:
#SignSymGrp eq 2^n*Factorial(n);

SignSymGrp;

